# How can I get my server to UDP multicast to clients across the internet? Do I need a special multicast IP address?

Tags: python, sockets, unity-game-engine, networking, udp

I am creating a multiplayer game and I would like the communication between my server program (written in python) and the clients (written in c# - Unity) to happen via UDP sockets.

I recently came across the concept of **UDP Multicast**, and it sounds like it could be much better for my use case as opposed to using **UDP Unicast** , because my server needs to update all of the clients (players) with the same content every interval. So, rather than sending multiple identical packets to all the clients with UDP unicast, I would like to be able to only send one packet to all the clients using multicast, which sounds much more efficient.

I am new to multicasting and my questions are:

**How can I get my server to multicast to clients across the internet?**

Do I need my server to have a special public multicast IP address? If so how do I get one?

Is it even possible to multicast across the internet? or is multicasting available only within my LAN?

And what are the pros and cons with taking the multicast approach?

Thank you all for your help in advance!!

Comment: Multicast will not work beyond the borders of your own network. You can't broadcast to the whole internet for obvious reasons.

Comment: The only way to multicast across the public Internet is to use a tunnel to the remote site. Multicast routing is very different than unicast routing, and all routers in the the path of the multicast packets must be configured with the same multicast routing protocol, so it will not work on the Internet. Encapsulating your multicast traffic in a unicast tunnel will work if the routers on both ends of the tunnel are configured to route the multicast traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't multicast on the Internet. Full stop.

Basically, multicast is only designed to work when there's someone in charge of the whole network to set it up. As you noted, that person needs to assign the multicast IP addresses, for example.